# Is the collapse of the wavefunction a contradiction of special relativity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, causality, faster-than-light, wavefunction-collapse

During the collapse of the wavefunction, the electron density spread over million of miles gets concentrated in very small region in literally no time. This means that electron density travels at speeds of infinite magnitude which is a contradiction of special relativity.Now see I'm a layman in SR and GR so my perception of SR/GR is limited to the media's and science journals' potrayal of SR/GR which can often be misleading. Also if it contradicts SR, has there been any plausible explanation for this particular phenomenon

Comment: The way to phrase the "speed limit" in quantum mechanics is through microcausality which is the statement that operators supported on spacelike separated points should commute. This would mean there is no problem but "collapse" is still a flawed conception of what happens to a wavefunction. A conceptually simpler explanation of observations (although it takes more getting used to) is that the wavefunction for a system and observer evolves smoothly but it evolves toward a state where it is no longer possible to talk about the system and observer separately.

Comment: This is only a problem if you think that the wave function represents a real "thing" out there in the world. We sometimes use the wave function as an approximate electron number density, as in descriptions of metals, but the wave function is not actually an "electron density". There are interpretations of quantum mechanics in which the wave function is *epistemic*, i.e., it represents (in varying ways, depending on the interpretation) the experimenter's knowledge about the system, or at least their willingness to place bets on what's going to happen. Then, no violation of SR occurs.

Comment: Does that mean that the other interpretations which do not consider wave function to be epistemic are wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't think that the wavefunction is a smeared out form of the electron, which condenses to a point-like particle through a physical collapse. The wavefunction represents the probability that the electron might be found at any given location. If you find the electron in Place A, you then know immediately it can not be in Place B, even if Place B is a trillion miles away- you do not have to depend upon something moving faster than light to confirm your knowledge.

Comment: Does that mean that the interpretations of QM which state that a particle is present everywhere/spread over a certain region until it is measured are wrong

Comment: I don't know of any mainstream interpretations that take that point of view, Tim; although popular science articles written about quantum mechanics contain all kinds of opinions.

Comment: This reminds me of an interpretation of a schrodinger's cat , stating that the cat is alive and dead at the same time. I seriously doubt the validity of the source though. By collapsing the wavefunction to an extremely small region we have very little idea about the electron's position exactly before the measurement.Going by this interpretation of schrodinger's cat, the electron is present at many places simulataneously before the measurement.Is this interpretation one of those personal opinions or is it a quite popular one?

Comment: If this interpretation is true then before the measurement, the particle would be present at a lot of places simultaneously ,some of them really really far away from the measured position. And suddenly it stops existing at all of these places and appears in a small region. This again leads to the speed of electrons being infinite.Please feel free to correct me

Comment: Again, I think you are either misreading a mainstream interpretation of QM. The electron's wavefunction gives the probability of locating the electron at a given point. That doesn't mean that the electron is simultaneously at all the points in space where it may be found. As for Schrodinger's cat- the idea of it being simultaneously alive and dead was invented by Schrodinger to highlight how nonsensical it was to take a literal interpretation of a superposition of two options.

Comment: In conclusion no particle cannot be a superposition of two options at the same time?

Comment: No, that's not right. But you are interpreting a superposition literally. A superposition just means that a wavefunction can be expanded as a mathematical sum over other basis functions. And that is always true- every wavefunction can be expressed as such an expansion.

Comment: So the electron was present at a single point in space before the measurement but we just dont know where it was

Comment: Possibly- that interpretation gets rid of the need for faster-than-light physical collapse. However, the point about quantum mechanics is that we don't know what 'really' happens. We do know that whenever electrons are detected they appear to be point like particles with no internal structure.

Comment: Last question. Are humans just unable to predict where the electron was before measurement but in reality the electron was present at a single fixed point?